# Dual Boot windows and Ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

[Partition selection menu picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCy8G.jpg)

Im trying to dual boot ubuntu with windows 10 on my desktop computer. i did shrink a partition and processed with the installation, but in the middle where you have to select the free space partition to create a swap partition and a ext partition, there i dont see the free space device in selection menu. kindly please help. the selection menu picture is attached.

Comment: Is Windows UEFI or BIOS. With FAT32 probably UEFI, but you are missing the Microsoft system reserved.? What is the unknown sda4? Can you click change on it?  You cannot create partition in Windows for Ubuntu. Make sure Windows fast startup is off.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and 8 & 10 are essentially the same: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system